# How to Install Manually Downloaded .box for Vagrant

Tags: laravel, vagrant, ubuntu-14.04

I manage to install Vagrant on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS pc. How can I install vagrant box which I downloaded manually from a URL? I want to install Laravel Homestead but it will always fail because of my network connection. I want to download it from this link `https://vagrantcloud.com/laravel/boxes/homestead/versions/11/providers/virtualbox.box` but I don't know what to do after I downloaded the box.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can install downloaded box using this command

`vagrant box add laravel/homestead path/to/your/box/file.box`

Source: https://laracasts.com/forum/?p=1615-laravel-vagrant-homestead/0

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to try this after I finish downloading homestead box. I'll accept it later

Comment: When I go to link https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead/versions/0.2.7/providers/virtualbox.box it downloads file `hc-download`. What wrong is being done

Comment: @Volatil3 it is the same file just rename it and add .box extension. However it is a server response to download that file by that name.

Comment: Its really save my time. 
I follow your suggestion. Additionally i had to prevent update

       config.vm.box_check_update = false

Then it works fine. I hope it will help for someone

Answer (score 9):

I am able to run this command on win7:

```
box add homestead file:///c:/homestead.box
```

Also this one is working:

```
box add homestead file:///c:\homestead.box
```

Comment: The first trick worked for me on Windows 10. Thanks a lot dude.

Comment: thanks a lot. I downloaded several times for the error message "could not open the file xxxx.box" until I found your answer.

Comment: box command not recognised. How do I get it?

Answer (score 2):

Boxes also can be added using metadata json file, in which some additional configs can be provided, along with box name and its local path.

For example create metadata.json file and provide version (7.0.0) of importing box in it:

```
{
  "name": "laravel/homestead",
  "versions": [
    {
      "version": "7.0.0",
      "providers": [
        {
          "name": "virtualbox",
          "url": "file:///Users/path/to/box/virtualbox.box"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Then add box running `vagrant box add` command with metadata.json file path parameter:

```
vagrant box add laravel/homestead /path/to/metadata.json
```

**Additional info:** When version is not provided, imported box will have version 0 by default. And if there is check for minimum box version, when running `vagrant up` it will start to download box from internet instead of using already imported one.