# Installing Laravel 5's Homestead

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, homestead

I have recently been trying too hard to actually learn and install Laravel but it's really hard to keep pace with the installation process. I'm currently on Windows 7 and I'm on this stage where I am already to add the vagrant box. It simply says:

vagrant box add laravel/homestead

and it asked what provider I will be working with and I chose "1" which is virtualbox but the download really seemed to get too slow that it just stops and gets errors as it downloads and I've tried for like a week already just trying to work this command. I tried to download the file using the IDM and had the file "virtualbox.box" but I don't know what I'd do with it. And I found that the file was actually too large to handle and to be downloaded continuously.

Someone please help me on how I could proceed on this. As it factually seems, we really have a very slow internet connection to continually download the file. Is there a way to install the manually downloaded file on IDM that I've had? Forgive me for sounding dumb. It's my first time working with PHP Frameworks for a project and I have been stuck installing. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is might be what you are looking for

[How to Install Manually Downloaded .box for Vagrant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26655516/how-to-install-manually-downloaded-box-for-vagrant)

I did not try it but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

To install laravel on Homestead VM, there are a few steps you need to follow.

******IMPORTANT STEP********

Make sure that you have windows virtualization turned ON in your BIOS. This will save you a few hours if you are installing it for the first time.

You will also need to install [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) and [Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/) before starting the installation of Homestead.

Make sure you install the correct versions for Windows PC.

The main advantages of using Homestead is that it provides a Linux virtual machine where you can easily install packages. It does comes with a lot of packages installed.

http://deepdivetuts.com/installing-laravel-5-4-on-windows-machine-using-homestead

Answer (score -1):

Laravel/Homestead box download link (Manually)

This is for thr version 1.0.1 (you can change the "20160818.0.0" to the version number)

https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/boxes/precise64/versions/20160818.0.0/providers/virtualbox.box