# laravel homestead SSL

Tags: php, laravel, curl

Adding the laravel/homestead box to Vagrant installation using the following command in my terminal gave error

C:\Users\MM>vagrant box add laravel/homestead

Error:

> The box 'laravel/homestead' could not be found or could not be
>   accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private box on
>   HashiCorp's Atlas, please verify you're logged in via `vagrant login`.
>   Also, please double-check the name. The expanded URL and error message
>   are shown below:
>
> URL: ["https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/homestead"] Error: SSL
>   certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate More
>   details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
>
> curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a
>   "bundle"  of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the
>   default  bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
>   using the --cacert option. If this HTTPS server uses a certificate
>   signed by a CA represented in  the bundle, the certificate
>   verification probably failed due to a  problem with the certificate
>   (it might be expired, or the name might  not match the domain name in
>   the URL). If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the
>   certificate, use  the -k (or --insecure) option.

Comment: i try this and it worked vagrant box add --insecure laravel/homestead

Comment: Please post the solution from you comment as an answer and accept it (there's nothing wrong with answering your own question if you find the solution yourself).

Comment: But i do not think it is complete answer

Comment: If that's the only thing you needed to do in your case, then it's an solution to your problem, which makes it a valid answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<1>Download virtual.box and You can install downloaded box using this command

vagrant box add laravel/homestead path\to\virtual.box

[How to Install Manually Downloaded .box for Vagrant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26655516/how-to-install-manually-downloaded-box-for-vagrant)

<2>Or try this

vagrant box add --insecure laravel/homestead