# Box 'laravel/homestead' could not be found

Tags: laravel, vagrant, vagrantfile, homestead

I have downloaded the `laravel/homestead` box manually from [here](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead).

I successfully add the box:

```
vagrant box add file:///path/to/the/laravel/homestead.box --name 'laravel/homestead'
```

but when I run `vagrant up` it says: `Box 'laravel/homestead' could not be found` even though `vagrant box list` shows the box.

The download page says that run `vagrant init laravel/homestead` that generates a `vagrantfile` but the `laravel/homestead` repository itself provides a `vagrantfile`.

I can `vagrant up` with the `vagrantfile` that is generated with `vagrant init laravel/homestead` but it lacks the essential configs inside the `laravel/homestead` repository's `vagrantfile`.

This is the `vagrantfile` that is generated

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# All Vagrant configuration is done below. The "2" in Vagrant.configure
# configures the configuration version (we support older styles for
# backwards compatibility). Please don't change it unless you know what
# you're doing.
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  # The most common configuration options are documented and commented below.
  # For a complete reference, please see the online documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com.

  # Every Vagrant development environment requires a box. You can search for
  # boxes at https://atlas.hashicorp.com/search.
  config.vm.box = "laravel/homestead"

  # Disable automatic box update checking. If you disable this, then
  # boxes will only be checked for updates when the user runs
  # `vagrant box outdated`. This is not recommended.
  # config.vm.box_check_update = false

  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine. In the example below,
  # accessing "localhost:8080" will access port 80 on the guest machine.
  # config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080

  # Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
  # using a specific IP.
  # config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"

  # Create a public network, which generally matched to bridged network.
  # Bridged networks make the machine appear as another physical device on
  # your network.
  # config.vm.network "public_network"

  # Share an additional folder to the guest VM. The first argument is
  # the path on the host to the actual folder. The second argument is
  # the path on the guest to mount the folder. And the optional third
  # argument is a set of non-required options.
  # config.vm.synced_folder "../data", "/vagrant_data"

  # Provider-specific configuration so you can fine-tune various
  # backing providers for Vagrant. These expose provider-specific options.
  # Example for VirtualBox:
  #
  # config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  #   # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
  #   vb.gui = true
  #
  #   # Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
  #   vb.memory = "1024"
  # end
  #
  # View the documentation for the provider you are using for more
  # information on available options.

  # Define a Vagrant Push strategy for pushing to Atlas. Other push strategies
  # such as FTP and Heroku are also available. See the documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/push/atlas.html for more information.
  # config.push.define "atlas" do |push|
  #   push.app = "YOUR_ATLAS_USERNAME/YOUR_APPLICATION_NAME"
  # end

  # Enable provisioning with a shell script. Additional provisioners such as
  # Puppet, Chef, Ansible, Salt, and Docker are also available. Please see the
  # documentation for more information about their specific syntax and use.
  # config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
  #   sudo apt-get update
  #   sudo apt-get install -y apache2
  # SHELL
end
```

it has this setting:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|  
    config.vm.box = "laravel/homestead"
end
```

I tried to add this to the default `laravel/homestead`'s `vagrantfile` but it didn't work.

```
require 'json'
require 'yaml'

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"
confDir = $confDir ||= File.expand_path("~/.homestead")

homesteadYamlPath = confDir + "/Homestead.yaml"
homesteadJsonPath = confDir + "/Homestead.json"
afterScriptPath = confDir + "/after.sh"
aliasesPath = confDir + "/aliases"

require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/scripts/homestead.rb')

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
    if File.exists? aliasesPath then
        config.vm.provision "file", source: aliasesPath, destination: "~/.bash_aliases"
    end

    if File.exists? homesteadYamlPath then
        Homestead.configure(config, YAML::load(File.read(homesteadYamlPath)))
    elsif File.exists? homesteadJsonPath then
        Homestead.configure(config, JSON.parse(File.read(homesteadJsonPath)))
    end

    if File.exists? afterScriptPath then
        config.vm.provision "shell", path: afterScriptPath
    end

    ## HERE I added the setting ############################################
    config.vm.box = "laravel/homestead"
    ########################################################################
end
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The Vagrantfile provided by the [laravel/homstead project](https://github.com/laravel/homestead/blob/master/Vagrantfile) is more advanced than a generic Vagrantfile that is generated by `vagrant init`

The Vagrantfile provided by the laravel/homstead project uses some ruby code to assist in setting up the vagrant environment. What we can see from the [homestead ruby code](https://github.com/laravel/homestead/blob/master/scripts/homestead.rb) is that it is checking that you have a box with a version greater than or equal to 0.4.0:

`config.vm.box_version = settings["version"] ||= ">= 0.4.0"`

As you added the box manually you will see that it is present on your local machine:

```
$ vagrant box list
laravel/homestead               (virtualbox, 0)
```

Note however the number next to the provider is 0. That number is the box version. As the box was added manually the box metadata was not available and by default you will get a version of 0.

When you now do a `vagrant up` the code is checking if you have a box >= 0.4.0 which you don't have so is why you are getting `Box 'laravel/homestead' could not be found`.  It would then attempt to download the box at the minimal version required.

To circumvent around this you could create a metadata.json file locally in the same directory as your downloaded box file. e.g:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/homestead",
    "versions": [{
        "version": "0.4.0",
        "providers": [{
            "name": "virtualbox",
            "url": "file:///path/to/homestead.box"
        }]
    }]
}
```

Then run `vagrant box add metadata.json`

This will install the box with a version and can be confirmed by:

```
$ vagrant box list
laravel/homestead               (virtualbox, 0.4.0)
```

You will now be able to perform `vagrant up` using your local box.

Comment: Thank you very much, I couldn't `vagrant box add metadata.json` so I just edited the `box_version` in the `homestead.rb` to `>= 0`

Comment: Thank you but I also think we need to be careful about adding correct version in metadata.json file.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. 2 years after and still is the right answer, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I have solved the problem by following. I test only on Mac El-capitan.

```
vagrant box add laravel/homestead homestead.box
```

it shows the following:

```
==> box: Box file was not detected as metadata. Adding it directly...
==> box: Adding box 'laravel/homestead' (v0) for provider: 
    box: Unpacking necessary files from: file:///Users/lwinmaungmaung/Vagrant%20Boxes/Homestead/homestead.box
==> box: Successfully added box 'laravel/homestead' (v0) for 'virtual box'!
```

And then I changed to vagrant file directory

```
cd ~/.vagrant.d/
```

Then list files and I saw My boxes

```
cent   hashicorp-VAGRANTSLASH-precise64      laravel-VAGRANTSLASH-homestead
```

and choose to laravel by `cd laravel-VAGRANTSLASH-homestead`

and ls and see `0`

I command by `mv 0 0.4.0`

When I list by `vagrant box list`

```
cent                (virtualbox, 0)
hashicorp/precise64 (virtualbox, 0)
laravel/homestead   (virtualbox, 0.4.0)
```

Then I edit Vagrant Homestead file `vi ~/Homestead/Vagrantfile`
and add the following:

```
config.vm.box = "laravel/homestead"
config.vm.box_url = "https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/homestead"
config.vm.box_version = "0.4.0"
config.vm.box_check_update = false
```

and then `vagrant up`

I hope it will works for some whose cannot add by metadata.json directly. Thanks.

Comment: Works like a charm!!   but I also have to add a file named "metadata_url" 
 inside  "laravel-VAGRANTSLASH-homestead"  directory with the following content: "https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/homestead".

Answer (score 2):

if someone have the same probelm and useing win, check if ms visual libraries are ok, the main is curl.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=5555

Answer (score 1):

Why download the box manually, if you can let Vagrant do all that for you?

As said in the homestead documentation:
`vagrant box add laravel/homestead` will add and download the box for you.

"If this command fails, you may have an old version of Vagrant that requires the full URL:"
`vagrant box add laravel/homestead https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead`

You can add a box manually like so:
`vagrant box add laravel/homestead path/to/your/box/file.box`

[How to Install Manually Downloaded .box for Vagrant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26655516/how-to-install-manually-downloaded-box-for-vagrant)

Comment: I have a slow connection

Comment: Old version of vagrant was causing this issue for me. Upgrading to latest & upgrading plugins fixed everything up.

Answer (score 1):

El-Capitan OS

Vagrant 2.2.14

Virtualbox 6

> Go to you directory like: /user/(name)/Homestead/scripts

This directory is where you make vagrant init and other installation processes.

Open **homestead.rb** file with sublime text or text editor then change the following:

`config.vm.box_version = settings['version'] ||= '‍‍‍‍‍~> 9'`

> TO

`config.vm.box_version = settings['version'] ||= '‍‍‍‍‍>= 10.1.1'`

after this changings you can start your vagrant in the directory

```
vagrant up
```

This will take some minutes to import your box into virtualbox.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the accepted answer but still it was trying to download the virtualbox "box". I had to modify the following settings in scripts/homestead.rb

```
#config.vm.box_version = settings["version"] ||= ">= 1.0.0"                 
config.vm.box_url = "file:///home/divick/Homestead/virtualbox.box"
```

Note I have commented out the version line because it was complaining with the following message:

```
Bringing machine 'homestead-7' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> homestead-7: Box 'laravel/homestead' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    homestead-7: Box Provider: virtualbox
    homestead-7: Box Version: >= 1.0.0
==> homestead-7: Box file was not detected as metadata. Adding it directly...
You specified a box version constraint with a direct box file
path. Box version constraints only work with boxes from Vagrant
Cloud or a custom box host. Please remove the version constraint
and try again.
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing this issue, make sure you [upgrade your vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/installation/upgrading.html) and adding `laravel/homestead` should get installed without issues.