# Add Vagrant .box file failing

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

Instead of running `vagrant box add ubuntu/trusty64` I want to download the `.box` file manually (like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26655516/how-to-install-manually-downloaded-box-for-vagrant)).

I downloaded the file from here:
https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty64/versions/14.04/providers/virtualbox.box

When I run `vagrant box add test123 ~/Downloads/trusty-server-cloudimg-amd64-vagrant-disk1.box` the following output results:

```
==> box: Box file was not detected as metadata. Adding it directly...
==> box: Adding box 'test123' (v0) for provider:
    box: Unpacking necessary files from: file:///XYZ/trusty-server-cloudimg-amd64-vagrant-disk1.box
An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.
```

(There is no further error message)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vagrant box could not be found or could not be accessed in the remote catalog - incompatible curl version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40473943/vagrant-box-could-not-be-found-or-could-not-be-accessed-in-the-remote-catalog/40474205#40474205)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your vagrant version `Vagrant 1.8.7` you can try this.

```
sudo rm -rf /opt/vagrant/embedded/bin/curl
```

This worked for me.